# Flask blueprint: meaning of first input and output object

Tags: python, flask

I need an explanation, not help fixing a particular code problem.

I'm writing a Flask app, using suggestions I've found in 3 different tutorials.  Today's question is prompted by the fact that most blogs use examples that have exactly the names for folders, files, blueprint objects, and the first argument in Blueprint itself.

Examples are often in directory "web" with file name `web.py` (or `__init__.py`) and inside that file we see:

```
from flask import Blueprint
web = Blueprint('web', __name__)
```

There are too many usages of the word `web`, I want to understand the separate effect of each.

Then in the app factory, these examples have something to the effect of

```
from app.web import web
app.register_blueprint(web)
```

Again, the characters `web` are used too many times for clarity.

In the example I'm working with, I defy this convention and have a folder named "auth". In there, I have `__init__.py` that creates a blueprint object "auth_bp". Today I need your help to understand what is the impact of using a different name as the first argument:

```
auth_bp = Blueprint('auth_whatever', __name__)
```

Throughout the code for the routes, everything seems to work using code like:

```
@auth_bp.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
```

So the name of the route seems to be `auth_bp`.

Except, in development mode, there are errors when the code gets to the section of code for views that asks for `url_for`.  It appears the name of the blueprint at that point needs to be `auth_whatever` in my experiments.

```
url_for('auth_whatever.login')
```

Am I understanding this correctly?  The "name" of the blueprint in the decorator is `auth_bp` but the name to be used in `url_for` is the name I gave in the first argument of `Blueprint`?

I would agree entirely if you say "just name those all the same thing and it will work."  But I hate to do that without truly understanding WTF is going on.

Comment: Why the -1? Because I had python-3 as a tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first code snippet, you create the variable `web` and assign it an object of the type `Blueprint`. You can now use the name `web` to refer to this object and manipulate it in your code. During its creation you pass it the name "web". As you already figured out further down in your text, this means you have to use this value in your calls to `url_for`. This is explained in the [documentation of Blueprint Objects](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#blueprint-objects):

> class flask.Blueprint(name, [...])
>
> [...]
>
> name – The name of the blueprint. Will be prepended to each endpoint name.

Because this typically happens the (sub-)package `web/__init__.py` you can access the variable `web` by importing it as seen in your second code snippet as `from app.web import web`. The first "web" refers to the package and the second "web" refers to the variable you defined previously. The next line then passes the variable to `app.register_blueprint()`.

Comment: If you have follow up questions, please leave a comment and I will extend my answer if I can.

Comment: I do not understand why the decorators use the left hand side name "auth_bp" while the name used by the Blueprint is just "auth". I understand that is a fact, but it surprised me enough to ask about it.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I agree with your description. It is same conclusion I wanted to get confirmation about.